# :Hover not working on Internet Exploror 10 or Older

Tags: css

I have this CSS Class :

```
<style>
.container { background-color:#FFF; }
.container:hover { background-color:#000; }
</style>
```

Its Hover is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

Here is the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6fwNX/1/

Any Solution ?

Comment: Post your html and make jsfiddle so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Please check the Fiddle in POST

Answer (score 2):

Add the HTML4.1 Doctype like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional// EN" "http://www.w3.org/ TR/html4/loose.dtd">.
```

Add it at the top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test anything like it, but it looks like IE doesn't know the size (height/width) of your container. Try to specify height and width and display:block; (or inline-block)

Comment: I've tested it in windows 8/7 - IE 9/10 and both works .. So this fiddle doesn't work for you in IE10?